# Trigger.new List During a Transaction

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext, transaction

This is a question I have always wondered. I have a series of classes and methods that modify the Trigger.new case list records as the list is handed off to each class and method.

Apex goes down the lines of classes and methods synchronously in the trigger. I assume after each class and method changes trigger.new (field values updated, etc.), it then hands the new list of case records to the next class and method(s) and so on.

I assume the original unmodified trigger.new list is not handed to the next class or method, the modified one in is.

That is my understanding of how the transaction works. I ask this to prevent my cobweb of classes and methods from becoming too dependent on the order of execution within each trigger context variable.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert) {

if(Trigger.isBefore) {
   if(Trigger.isInsert) {

        QualifyCase.QualifyRecordType(Trigger.new);
        ProcessCase.ConvertChars(Trigger.new);
        RouteCase.DetermineOwner(Trigger.new);

    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Where is the modification on the `trigger.new`?

Comment: Your post doesn't actually contain a question.

Comment: Related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165153/unable-to-rerender-in-visualforce-component/166812

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection itself remains the same, but the context records are modified. Consider the following contrived example:

**Service Layer**

```
public with sharing class MyObjectService
{
    public static void setTextField1(List<MyObject__c> records)
    {
        for (MyObject__c record : records)
        {
            record.Field1__c = 'Hello';
        }
    }
    public static void setTextField2(List<MyObject__c> records)
    {
        for (MyObject__c record : records)
        {
            record.Field2__c = 'World';
        }
    }
    public static void setTextField3(List<MyObject__c> records)
    {
        for (MyObject__c record : records)
        {
            record.Field3__c = record.Field1__c + record.Field2__c;
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger MyObject on MyObject__c (before insert)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert)
        {
            MyObjectService.setTextField1(trigger.new);
            MyObjectService.setTextField2(trigger.new);
            MyObjectService.setTextField3(trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, when you call `setTextField2`, each record being processed will have `Field1__c` already set to `'Hello'`. Then when you call `setTextField3`, both `Field1__c` and `Field2__c` will already be set, so `Field3__c` should equal `'HelloWorld'` for each record.

Comment: +1 for the clean and simple code. But I'm still not understanding the question here. :(

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think OP is trying to understand if changes made to the context records will persist across different method calls, to which the answer would be yes.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, that is what I am asking. It was hard to put it in wording.

Comment: @ManifestDestiny Cool. Yeah then you can depend on each individual record being modified for the remainder of the transaction. If you had multiple methods writing to one field, last executed would win. If you have one method that writes to a field then another that depends on that value, it will be populated.